# Does Swift support automatic generation of operators?

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm looking to avoid writing unnecessary code. If I define `==` and `<` for a type, is it possible to automatically obtain `<=` (`<` or `==`), `>` (not `<` and not `==`), or `>=` (not `<`)? I would think Swift would provide these operators for free, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your type conform to `Equatable`, it will provide a default implementation of `!=` based on your `==`.

If you make your type conform to `Comparable`, it will provide default implementations of `>`, `<=`, and `>=` based on your `<`.

Note that `Comparable` extends `Equatable`, so you must also provide `==` to conform to `Comparable`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That's exactly how `Comparable` protocol works. You only have to define 2 operators: `<` and `==`. Swift will figure out the rest.

```
struct MyStruct : Comparable {
    var value: Int
}

func == (lhs: MyStruct, rhs: MyStruct) -> Bool {
    return lhs.value == rhs.value
}

func < (lhs: MyStruct, rhs: MyStruct) -> Bool {
    return lhs.value < rhs.value
}

let a = MyStruct(value: 1)
let b = MyStruct(value: 42)

print(b > a) // We never defined `>` operator
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Implement `==` from [`Equatable`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/equatable) and `<` from [`Comparable`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/comparable), and the rest of the operators will use the default implementations as you expect.

> To add `Comparable` conformance to your custom types, define the `<` and `==` operators as static methods of your types. The `==` operator is a requirement of the `Equatable` protocol, which `Comparable` extends—see that protocol’s documentation for more information about equality in Swift. Because default implementations of the remainder of the relational operators are provided by the standard library, you’ll be able to use `!=`, `>`, `<=`, and `>=` with instances of your type without any further code.